# Lock statement outside transcation

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, concurrency, locking, hibernate-criteria

What happens when we put a lock statement outside transaction ?

When two concurrent request try to take lock on the same data, will both of them be able to acquire lock on the data ?

Sample Code for reference :

```
//Starting point for the request
@Override
    public void receiveTransferItems(String argumet1, String refernceId, List<Item> items, long messageId)
            throws Exception {
        ParentDTO parent = DAO.lockByReferenceid(referenceId);
        if (parent == null) {
            throw new Exception(referenceId + "does not exist");
        }

        updateData(parent);

        for (Item item : items) {
            receiveItem(td, td.getWarehouseId(), item.getItemSKU(), item.getItemStatus(), item.getQtyReceived(), messageId);
        }

    }
    
    
    private void updateData(ParentDTO td) throws DropShipException {

        //perform some logical processing and then execute update 
        DAO.update(td);
    }
    
    
    
     private void receiveItem(ParentDTO td, String warehouseId, String asin, String itemStatus, int quantity, long messageId)
            throws Exception {
    
        /**
         * perform some logical processing
         * 
         **/
        //call is being made to another class to do the rest of the processing
        service.receive(td, asin, quantity, condition, container, messageId);
    }
```

```
@Override
    public void receive(
            ParentDTO parentDTO,
            String asin,
            int quantity,
            Condition condition,
            Container container,
            long messageId,
            DataAccessor accessor) throws Exception {



        List<ChildDTO> childDTOs =
            DAO.lockChildDTOItems(parentDTO.getReferenceId(), asin, condition,
                                                  CostInfoSource.MANIFEST);

        List<ChildDTO> filterItems = DAO
            .loadChildDTOItems(parentDTO.getReferenceId(), asin, condition.name());

        long totalExpectedQuantity = getTotalExpectedQuantity(filterItems);
        long totalReceivedQuantity = getTotalReceivedQuantity(filterItems);

        int quantityNormalReceived = 0;
        for (ChildDTO tdi : childDTOs) {
        
            int quantityReceived = 0;
            if (asinDropShipMsgAction != null) {
                quantity -= asinDropShipMsgAction.getInitialQuantity();
                quantityNormalReceived += asinDropShipMsgAction.getInitialQuantity();
            } else {
                quantityReceived = new DBOperationRunner<Integer>(accessor.getSessionManager()) {
                    @Override
                    protected Integer doWorkAndReturn() throws Exception {
                        return normalReceive(tdi, quantityLeft, container, MessageActionType.TS_IN, messageId);
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
          
        }

    }
    
    
    
    private int normalReceive(final ChildDTO childDTO,
                              int quantity,
                              final Container container,
                              final MessageActionType type,
                              long messageId)
        throws Exception {

        /**
         * perform some business logic
         * 
         * */
         
        DAO.update(childDTO);
        return someQuantity;
    }
```

Processing of locking function in STEP-1:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(XYZ.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("referenceId", referenceId)).setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT);
        return (XYZ) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Note : I am using hibernate and criteria as a DB framework and Postgres as a DB.

Comment: "*when we put a lock statement outside transaction*" - you can't. Everything runs in a transaction. If you don't manage them explicitly the statement (e.g. UPDATE) will run as a single statement, so the lock will be released immediately after the UPDATE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the sample algorithm which i have mentioned is actually running in production.

Comment: If you are not explicitly starting a transaction, then step 1 is one transaction, step 2 is one transaction, step 3 is one transaction and step 4 is another transaction. Although i would question the first "lock row" (assuming you mean `select .. for update`), as the UPDATE will lock the row as well. The only reason for doing that, if you did other things between step 1 and step 2 that you didn't tell us.

Comment: Please describe exactly (that is, show the SQL statement) what you mean by "locking a row".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe have updated the sample implementation of locking function that i am using to lock a particular row.

Comment: Ok, that is `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`. Now we'd need to know how exactly the transaction management happens.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i have updated a sample code which will help you in understanding how the transaction management happens